# I want to distribute two kinds of objects on instances (grid, or points in volume) with a gradient

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, collections

I am trying to distribute 2 objects in a collection on a grid (or volume) with a gradient using geometry nodes. What I mean by gradient is the density of a material in the center will decrease towards the periphery while density of other will increase. Like in the attached image:

[image]

I am pretty new to Blender or any sort of 3D modeling. I looked for the solution but could not find any solution using just geometry nodes. I do not want to realize instances and use shader editor. I would appreciate if anyone can help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this: put the two objects in a collection which you reference in *Geometry Nodes* through a *Collection Info* node. Make sure the node is set to *Separate Children* and *Reset Children*.

With a *Grid* you get the points for distributing the objects. Plug this and the collection into an *Instance on Points* node where you enable *Pick Instance*. In the *Instance Index* input you plug a *Random Value* node set to *Boolean*. Since you have two objects in the collection, their indices are 0 and 1.

The *Probability* value in the *Random Value* node defines the chance of the node giving out "true" i.e. 1, so to have less objects with the index 1 towards the border, the probability must go down towards 0.

To achieve this, you can use the *UV Map* output of the grid and a *Gradient Texture*. Move the UV map to the center of the grid by subtracting 0.5 on XYZ with a *Vector Math* node. To refine the distribution you can use a *Vector Math* node set to scale to change how far out the object 1 will be appearing, and with for example a *Map Range* node you can vary the falloff. But a *Color Ramp* node or a *Float Curve* could be used as well.

[image: gradual distribution]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gordon for the great advice and quick response, how can apply the same approach to a 3D array created like: Volueme Cube --> Distribute points in Volume (Grid) --> Instance on Points. There is no embedded UV map like in the case of Grid.

Comment: Solved it! By using geometry proximity node. Thanks again! Your solution guided me a lot.